# Saving data values to multiple tables within same class ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to save data from the view to the database from one main view and 1 partial view. Here `AppRequest` is the main class and the others are `Purchase`, `PurchasingEmpl`, `PurchasingItems`.

But when I debug the code, to the controller `AppRequest` main view data will pass but other class data not showing. Also not passing to the other tables also. Can you help me with this?

These are my model classes:

```
public class AppRequest
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Request Type")]
    public int ReqType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Requesting By")]
    public int Req_By { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Requesting Date")]
    public DateTime Req_Date { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Request Location")]
    public int Req_Location { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Request Heading")]
    public string Req_Heading { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Cover Note")]
    public string Req_CoverNote { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
    public int Company_Id { get; set; }

    public bool Status { get; set; }

    public int Create_By { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created_Date { get; set; }
    public int Modified_By { get; set; }
    public DateTime Modified_Date { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public int Approval_Status { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Purchase> Purchase { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public  Purchase PurchaseItem { get; set; }
}

#region Purchase
public class Purchase
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("AppRequest")]
    public int Req_Id { get; set; }
    public virtual AppRequest AppRequest { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<PurchasingEmpl> PurchasingEmpl { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<PurchasingItems> PurchasingItems { get; set; }
}

public class PurchasingEmpl
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Purchase")]
    public int Purchase_Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Purchase Purchase { get; set; }
    public int Emp_Id { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
}

public class PurchasingItems
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Purchase")]
    public int Purchase_Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Purchase Purchase { get; set; }
    public int Supp_Id { get; set; }
    public int Itm_Description_Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Unit_Amount { get; set; }
    public byte[] Attachment { get; set; }
    public decimal Qty { get; set; }
    public string Recomandation { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public bool Settled { get; set; } = false;
    public string PoNo { get; set; }
}
```

This is the controller

```
public ActionResult Create(AppRequest appRequest)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            appRequest.Create_By = int.Parse(((System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).FindFirst("UserId").Value);
            appRequest.Created_Date = DateTime.Now;
            appRequest.Modified_By= int.Parse(((System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).FindFirst("UserId").Value);
            appRequest.Modified_Date = DateTime.Now;
            appRequest.Status = true;

            db.AppRequest.Add(appRequest);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(appRequest);
}
```

`````
HTML View

````
@model Asp_PASMVC.Models.AppRequest

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

    List<SelectListItem> ReqTypes = (List<SelectListItem>)TempData.Peek("RequestTyleList");
    List<SelectListItem> Employees = (List<SelectListItem>)TempData.Peek("EmployeeList");
    List<SelectListItem> Location = (List<SelectListItem>)TempData.Peek("LocationList");
    List<SelectListItem> Companies = (List<SelectListItem>)TempData.Peek("ComapnyList");
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <section class="content">

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <!-- Default box -->
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header" >
                            <h3 class="card-title">Request Header Details</h3>

                            <div class="card-tools">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-card-widget="collapse" title="Collapse">
                                    <i class="fas fa-minus"></i>
                                </button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-card-widget="remove" title="Remove">
                                    <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">


                            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group row">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReqType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ReqType, ReqTypes, new { @class = "js-dropdown" })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReqType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                               
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group row">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Company_Id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Company_Id, Companies, new { @class = "js-dropdown" })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Company_Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group row">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Req_By, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Req_By, Employees, new { @class = "js-dropdown" })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Req_By, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group row">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Req_Location, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Req_Location, Location, new { @class = "js-dropdown" })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Req_Location, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-6">
                                    <div class="form-group row">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Req_Heading, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                                        <div class="col-6">
                                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Req_Heading, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Req_Heading, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group row">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Req_Date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Req_Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "js-datepicker" } })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Req_Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-6">
                                    <div class="form-group row">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Req_CoverNote, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                                        <div class="col-6">
                                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Req_CoverNote, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Req_CoverNote, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>




                        <!-- /.card-body -->
                     
                        <!-- /.card-footer-->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.card -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>


    <section class="content">

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <!-- Default box -->
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h3 class="card-title">Request Main Details</h3>

                            <div class="card-tools">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-card-widget="collapse" title="Collapse">
                                    <i class="fas fa-minus"></i>
                                </button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-card-widget="remove" title="Remove">
                                    <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">

                            @Html.Partial("_Purchase", Model.PurchaseItem);

                            <!-- /.card-body -->
                            <div class="card-footer">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.card-footer-->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.card -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </section>




    

}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>



````
`````

Comment: Please also provide your HTML and Javascript file to let others know how you deal with your data and transfer it. That would help.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. You are posting your form to `Create()` and the `appRequest` is missing child properties? Is the `Purchase` collection missing? Share the partial views that are part of the form as well.

Comment: @Jasen. Process is like this, In the create view, there are 1 partial view `Purchase `. In that patial view there are another 2 partial views. `PurchasingEmpl` and `PurchasingItems`. So when loading the view,1st section shows the `AppRequest` details and 2nd section the `purchase` partial view. So when I fill all the data and hit Submit, only `AppRequest` view data pass to the controller, other partial view datas not passing to the controller.